# solving conic equation for a set of points using Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations, equation-solving

let's say I have 6 points (x,y)and the general equation for a conic section Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0. is there a way I can find A,B,C,D,E,F?

I know that for a linear equation I can solve this with a matrix but it won't seem to work since all of the equation are equal to 0
any help on this topic would be appreciated

Comment: Your question is not related to programming, please move it to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Shiko actually I'm looking for a way to do it using matlab...I know how the equations can be solved by hand but I can't seem to find the right functions to do so in matlab

Comment: Have you tried this function `fit_conicLMA(XY,ParAini,LambdaIni)` reference https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32108-fitting-a-conic-to-a-given-set-of-points-using-levenberg-marquardt-method

Comment: @Shiko yes,I have tried to understand how it works but I can't seem to get it right,it  looks like I have to supply the A,B,C,D,E,F values

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this (x and y are column vectors):

```
M=[x.^2, x.*y, y.^2, x, y, x*0+1];
[U,S,V]=svd(M)
Sol=V(:,end) %A,B,C,D,E,F
```